# Data structure for product details

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm building a query engine in Python. I'm looking for the suitable data structure for storing my data (I'm not allowed to use SQL, pandas.. etc.).

My data in the file looks like this:

```
Samsung-Galaxy-On5-Black-16GB-3GB-RAM-     Mobile
Peter England-Men-s-Solid-Casual-White-Shirt.    Shirt
Birdy-Fabric-Closet-Finish-Color-Blue-2-Door-.       Bird house
```

and thousands of records.

I want to read from the file and store. I thought of list of lists or list of dictionaries. I want faster retrieval. Queries would be simple. If anyone could suggest a better one. A piece of code would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about a csv file that you can read from and write to with pandas?

Comment: or `hdf5`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables

Comment: I'm not allowed to use pandas actually! I'm building one similar to pandas

Comment: I would recommend to use dictionaries. They can serve as an in-memory database. If you store the same objects in different dictionaries, you can have several keys pointing to the same "database entry", allowing for convenient and fast retrieval.

Comment: I would use a dictionary where each key would store a list. Your keys could be your object type (the right part of your example "mobile, shirt ...") since it seems the would be repeated. So you could have a fast access to the list where an specific object lies. You can also add more complexity and use another data structures instead of a simple list (or keep the list sorted). Multiple answers could be valid in here

Comment: @Priyanka.J: _I'm building one similar to pandas_ - this does not seem a great start. You have `csv` module in standard library, why inventng the wheel?

Comment: If you are using Python 3.7, you can use the new data classes. These are primarily made for storing Data: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/

Comment: @m33n So each key would contain multiple lists as mobile,shirt objects repeat.Is it? Can you help me with piece of code?